# Android Web View get shrink when keyboard popups

Tags: android, flash, webview

When i am calling the url (http://staging-nsw.tatainteractive.com/Admin/FlashCards/FlashCard_Android.html) in my Android app webview.

Whenever i tap on textbox the layout get shrink while it didn't shrink on default browser. 
and keyboard popup on top of browser.

How can i message to keyboard to popup on top of browser or browser should not shrink itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set attribute in manifeast.xml for that .android:softkeyboard="" values according to ur requirements.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible"